# Get SUM of Nullable Column using WHERE clause

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am having some problems retrieving the `SUM` of a column in EF6 using a `WHERE` clause.

I am using this:

```
double oh2 = raptorEntities.OnlineHistories
    .Where(us => us.Id == user.Id)
    .Sum(r => (double?) r.SessionTime) ?? 0; // Need the cast as we may get a null !
```

The idea is get the `SUM` of SessionTime column in OnlineHistories `WHERE` Userid = x

Now the SessionTime column is a computed column and contains values... and does allow `NULL`

Anyone able to fix this expression so that it works?

**UPDATE ONE**

With the suggested Fix:

```
double oh2 = raptorEntities.OnlineHistories.Where(us => us.Id == user.Id &&
 us.SessionTime.HasValue).Sum(r => r.SessionTime);
```

I have to cast it like so, and receive an error:

```
double oh2 = raptorEntities.OnlineHistories.Where(us => us.Id == user.Id &&
 us.SessionTime.HasValue).Sum(r => (double)r.SessionTime);
```

> Error     Error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type
>   'Edm.Double[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=]' of member 'SessionTime' in
>   type 'RaptorModel.OnlineHistory' is not compatible with
>   'SqlServer.int[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,StoreGeneratedPattern=Computed]'
>   of member 'SessionTime' in type
>   'RaptorModel.Store.OnlineHistory'.    RaptorDb    C:\Users\Dave\documents\visual
>   studio 2015\Projects\RaptorService\RaptorDb\RaptorModels.edmx 835

With the Mapping Looking like this:

```
<EntitySetMapping Name="OnlineHistories">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="RaptorModel.OnlineHistory">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="OnlineHistory">
                <ScalarProperty Name="SessionTime" ColumnName="SessionTime" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="UserId" ColumnName="UserId" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="OnlineAt" ColumnName="OnlineAt" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="OfflineAt" ColumnName="OfflineAt" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
```

UPDATE TWO:
SessionTime does not have a type:

[image: SessionType Table]
[image: SessionTime Properties]

Comment: Looks like you should change the type to `int?` in the edmx designer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just filter those rows out:

```
double oh2 = raptorEntities.OnlineHistories
.Where(us => us.Id == user.Id && us.SessionTime.HasValue)
.Sum(r => r.SessionTime);
```

**EDIT:**

You are looking in `edmx:Mappings`. Instead look in `edmx:StorageModels` for type. Also in `Sql Server` in `Object Explorer` expand `tables->OnlineHistories->Columns` and you probably should be able to see that type is `int`. Somehow in your model it is of type `double`. I can reproduce this error if I manually change column type from `int` to `double` in `edmx`. But by default it is created as `int` in my model. You can try to delete that table from model and import it again.

One note `Sum` function seems to eliminate `NULL`s itself:

```
double oh2 = raptorEntities.OnlineHistories
.Where(us => us.Id == user.Id)
.Sum(r => r.SessionTime);
```

Comment: @DaveGordon, What is the type of SessionTime?

Comment: SessionTime has no type! I have added pictures to show the table and the Properties as well.

Comment: @DaveGordon, there should be type. You are looking in `edmx:Mappings`. Instead look in `edmx:StorageModels` for type. Also in Sql Server in Object Explorer expand tables->OnlineHistories->Columns and you probably should be able to see that type is `int`. Somehow in your model it is of type double. I can reproduce this error if I manually change column type from `int` to `double` in `edmx`. But by default it is created as `int` in my model. Can you delete that table from model and import it again and try again?

Comment: Nakerui  Add you comment to your answer and I will mark it as correct. There was also a logic error in that I was comparing to the Id of the column and not the UserId... but that is sorted as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why not filter out the nulls?

```
double oh2 = 
raptorEntities
.OnlineHistories
.Where(us => us.Id == user.Id && us.SessionTime != null)
.Sum(r => (double)r.SessionTime);
```

Since you intend that the nulls are coalesced to zero, ignoring them will have no effect on the Sum.